# Weird rendering DIN font on Windows machines (only)

Tags: html, css, windows, fonts, font-face

I've a very weird problem with a font I use. It's DIN-medium & bold and I **only have this problem on Windows Machines** in IE & Chrome and probably also firefox.

This is the website where the problems occurs (also on other pages) > http://www.degraafengroot-nl.nl04.members.pcextreme.nl/wonen/

Here you can see the difference between Windows (BAD) & OSX Chrome (GOOD)

[image: Sample image]

I tried font-smoothing, different ttf to webfont tools, but I can't fix it.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Does the problem occur with any other fonts? Might be a bad font file source.

Comment: www.degraafengroot-nl.nl04.members.pcextreme.nl/din-medium here you can see that the font just works.